# Difference of to be exact and to be specific

Tags: phrase-usage

Are there any differences between **to be exact** and **to be specific**?

For example,

> It took decades for them to finish their mind-blowing invention, 24 years **to be exact**.

and

> It took decades for them to finish their mind-blowing invention, 24 years **to be specific**.

Can we use them at the start of a sentence and is **to be exact** used to *literally* indicate exact things? While **to be specific** is explicit about a thing? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To be exact* implies that it took exactly 24 years (so, not a round number of decades).

*To be specific* means that 24 years was the particular period of time that it took.

So, in effect, both mean the same thing in this context, with a slight difference in emphasis.